# Tools to pre-download iOS updates

Tags: ios, ipsw

Is there a tool for OSX or Windows that will automatically download all the current iOS ipsw files?

I work at a school and when someone has a problem with an iPad and we need to restore it, we have to wait for iTunes or Apple Configurator to download the latest update.
It would be really handy if we could automatically pre download the IPSW files so that they were ready to go as soon as they were needed.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can always download the files from [ipswdownloader.com](http://www.ipswdownloader.com).
I agree it looks shady but I use it a lot for my development devices and i never have any problems with it.
You can also find the ipsw files on your computer as described in [this article](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5376130), you might want to copy the files to another folder though because itunes will remove them automatically.

Comment: Note that it downloads mentioned on the from ipswdownloader.com are acctually directly linked to apple download server so I think it's pretty safe. For example iOS 8.1 for iPhone - http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS8.1/031-09660.20141020.Zt4Uu/iPhone7,1_8.1_12B411_Restore.ipsw

Comment: I have used that site on several occasions, however what I'd like is a tool to automatically download all the IPSWs before I need them rather than me downloading them when I discover I need them and then waiting 2 hours.

Comment: surely you don't need to download al of them, do you?
You need to download the latest versions available on your devices, apple doesn't sign older versions of iOS anymore so you have to install the highest possible.

Comment: @dennismuys No I dont need all of them. I should have said "all the latest IPSWs".

Comment: I don't think there is a tool available that does that